# sql select average from distinct column of table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlcommand

In my table I have some colms like this, (beside another cols)

```
col1 | col2
s1   |  5
s1   |  5
s2   |  3
s2   |  3
s2   |  3
s3   |  5
s3   |  5
s4   |  7
```

I want to have average of **ALL** col2 over Distinct col1.
(5+3+5+7)/4=5

Comment: Can you share the output you're expecting to get for this data? Your calculation and your text seem to contradict each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(T.col2)
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
    FROM yourtable) as T
```

Answer (score 5):

You are going to need a subquery.  Here is one way:

```
select avg(col2)
from (select distinct col1, col2
      from my_table
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Average is the sum of a set of values divided by the number of those value. Here, you want to divide by a count of the distinct values, so:

```
SELECT SUM(col2)/COUNT (DISTINCT col1)
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Dear, you summarize all valus of col2, not one for distinct col1.

Comment: This is what the OP's **text** suggests, albeit not his example. Let's ask the OP for clarifications

Answer (score 0):

You can just say

```
SELECT col1, AVG( col2 ) FROM my_table GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: This is wrong, it produces avg for each col1 distinct element separately!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT AVG(coll2) as Average From myTable Group by Col1,Col2
```